# Robot Framework: How to click checkbox by the value attribute

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, selenium3

Trying to check a specific check box in a dynamic grid. The only uniqueness for the targeted checkbox is it's value. The surrounding div is created by the grid object and is not really related to the value of the checkbox.

```
<div class="ricoLG_cell ricoLG_evenRow" id="ex2_2_0">
    <input onclick="wasChecked(this);" name="regids" type="checkbox" value="184685">
</div>
```

The xpath evaluates to :

```
//*[@id="ex2_2_0"]/input
```

which is not predictable. The value is predictable, but I don't know how to reference it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is predictable, reference it like any other attribute - like you did with the id:

```
//input[@value="184685"]
```

Comment: Cool! Worked! Thanks